# Norm of an operator on space of real polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $L:\mathbb{R}[X]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}[X]$ be an operator given by the following formula

$L\left(\sum\limits_n a_nX^n\right)=\sum\limits_n a_{2n}X^{2n}$.

We assume that on $\mathbb{R}[X]$ we have a norm $\|p\|=\int\limits_{-1}^{1}|p(t)|dt$.

Is this operator bounded ? If yes what is its norm ?

I tried to do it in a different ways, but all my ideas failed.

Comment: What are the coefficients $a_{2n}$

Comment: Think about $p=x^{2n}-x^{2n+1}$.

Comment: If $p=x^{2n}-x^{2n+1}$ then $L(p)=x^{2n}$ and $\|L(p)\|=\frac{1}{n}$, so I should choose $p_k=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k} (x^{2j}-x^{2j+1})$, then it gives me a sequence of polynomials, which have norms bounded by some constants, and $\|L(p_k)\|$ tends to $\infty$ if $k\rightarrow \infty$,right ?

Comment: @mikis you should be considering $\frac{\|L(p)\|}{\|p\|}$

Comment: Ok, but my example also works. I obtain $\|p_k\|\le 2-\log 4<1$ and $\|L(p_k)\|\ge \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Answer under repair; see comments below]*

---

Take $p = p_{n}(x) = x^{2n} - x^{2n+1}$, so that $L(p) = x^{2n}$.  We note that
$$
\|p\| = \int_{-1}^1 |p(t)|\,dt = 2\int_0^1 [t^{2n} - t^{2n+1}]\,dt = 2 \left[ \frac {1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\right] = \frac{1}{n(2n+1)}
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\|L(p)\| = \int_{-1}^1 t^{2n}\,dt = \frac{2}{2n+1}
$$
From there, it remains to be shown that $\left(\frac{p_n}{\|p_n\|}\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a bounded sequence for which the image under $L$ is unbounded.

Comment: $\int_{-1}^1 x^{2n} |1-x|dx \ne 2 \int_0^1 x^{2n}(1-x)dx$

Comment: @user1952009 oooh, wow, good catch.  I'm not sure what $L(q_n)$ would look like then, though.  I suppose there's always the possibility of using Stone-Weierstrass.

Comment: I could just multiply my sequence by a polynomial sequence $q_n$ that approaches $1_{[0,1]}$ uniformly (by invoking Stone-Weierstrass).  I'd like to avoid that if possible, though

Comment: we need two polynomials $p_n(x^2)$ and $x q_n(x^2)$ such that $p_n(x^2) + x q_n(x^2) \approx 0$ on $[-1;1]$ but not $p_n(x^2)$ alone. the problem is that $x q_n(x^2) $ is odd but $p_n(x^2)$ is even !! so that's impossible $\implies$ the operator is bounded ?

Answer (score 0):

for any two polynomials $P(x),Q(x)$ :

$$L\left(P(x^2)+ x Q(x^2)\right) = P(x^2)$$

now think to :

$$\min_{Q} \quad||P(x^2) + x Q(x^2)|| = \int_{-1}^1 \left|P(x^2)+x Q(x^2)\right| dx$$

because $P(x^2)$ is an even function while $x Q(x^2)$ is an odd function, the minimum is attained for $Q(x^2) = 0$.

thus :
$$||L(P(x^2)+x Q(x^2))||=||P(x^2)||\le ||P(x^2)+xQ(x^2)||$$

so the operator is bounded (which as shown in the discussion wouldn't be the case if we were considering the $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \,|.|\, dx$ norm instead !) and clearly its norm is $||L|| = 1$

*note : that a projection operator on a Banach space is bounded or not seems to be related to the [Schauder basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis#Relation_to_Fourier_series), so I would be glad if someone could explain in term of Shauder basis why $L$ is bounded for the $\int_{-1}^1 |.|dx$ norm but not for the $\int_0^1 |.|dx$*